# Sticky position left does not work in React app

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, css-position, styled-components

I am making a React project with Styled Components. I have a Horizontal Navbar that will stick to the top when scrolled, but it won't stick to the left when scrolling to the left or right. I have tried overflow: visible, display: inline-flex, and set left:0. Nothing works. Here is my Code:

The Styled Component:

```
// This is the horizontal nav bar
export const OrganizerMainNav = styled.nav`
    display: inline-flex;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0 !important;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 998; 
    align-self: flex-start;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100%;
   
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;

    background-color: rgba(34,39,46,1);
    min-height: 80px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(68,76,86,.5);
`;
```

(Full Source: https://github.com/Nellak2017/Task-Organizer-JS/blob/main/client/task-organizer-js/src/components/SideNav/SideNav.elements.js)

You can look at my Github repo for more context if needed.

I have tried everything I can think of and I am still frustrated. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `width: 100%;` , should be removed Else, as big as the parent, it sticks inside but will sctroll with it too. A sticky element remains in the flow and sticky untill it reaches the opposite edge of the container it sticks to or is being pushed by another sticky element. :) giv it a try without width.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. The issue was that the table was nested inside of a section, and the section did not have any CSS to handle overflowing children. Therefore, the simplest answer was to:

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

To the parent styled-component, so that the child table stayed within the section. This also eliminated the header having to move, by having the table scroll instead.